# Python Id call on an uninstantiated object

Tags: python

I'm getting a little confused about the `id` function and the integer that it returns, which is a reference to the Object's place in memory (I think that is correct).

So assume the first thing we do in the python shell is `>>> id(2)`, we immediately get an integer back. However, I never created an instance of an `int` Object. Is there an instantiation going on, on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, yes. The compiler instantiates it when it generates the bytecode for the VM to run.

Although integers from -1 through 256 are also special-cased in CPython.

```
import dis

def foo():
  a = 2

dis.dis(foo)
```

...

```
  6           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Can you unpack that first sentence a bit more?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Why is this confusing to you? It is the same as `"foo"` creating a string without an explicit call to `str`.